# PHP project - using <script> / </script>

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP project and see that `<script>...</script>` is used. What is this used for?

I see it in the code like:

```
else {
    echo '<script> userexist(); </script>';     
}
```

Comment: The script tag is for executing Javascript code.

Comment: What that will do is, once the page renders, it will call a JavaScript function.  You just have to make sure that function is there.

Comment: and....The function is userexist(). You can tell by the ()

Answer (score 1):

Anything printed by PHP is returned to the client. In this case the HTML is inserted into the webpage returned by the server. Script tags in HTML contain javascript. In this case it is inserting a call to the userexist() javascript function in your webpage.